# Permutation matrix times its transposed matrix is equal to Identity Matrix - Proof

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations, solution-verification

I want to ask if this is a valid proof that $P * P^T = I$

Let have permutation matrix $P^{m\times m}$

We can write it as :

$
P_{(a_1..a_n)} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
I_{a_1,*} \\
\vdots \\
I_{a_n,*} 
\end{pmatrix}
$

(Edit: where $P_{(a_1..a_n)}$ is any permutation matrix with permutation given as it's 'argument' And $I_{x, *}$ is a row number $x$ of identity matrix )

and his transposed matrix as:

$
{P_{(a_1..a_n)}}^T = 
\begin{pmatrix}
{(I_{a_1,*})}^T &
\cdots &
{(I_{a_n,*})}^T 
\end{pmatrix}
$

then we can $P \cdot  P^T$ express as :
\begin{equation*}
P_{(a_1..a_n)} \cdot {P_{(a_1..a_n)}}^T = 
\begin{pmatrix}
I_{a_1,*} \cdot {(I_{a_1,*})}^T & \cdots & I_{a_1,*} \cdot {(I_{a_n,*})}^T \\
\vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
I_{a_n,*} \cdot {(I_{a_1,*})}^T &  \cdots & I_{a_n,*} \cdot {(I_{a_n,*})}^T
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

We know that :

$I_{n,x} = 1\ if \ x=n \ else \ 0  $

$ {(I_{n,x})}^T = 1\ if \ x=n \ else \ 0$

Also we know that:

$(P_{(a_1..a_n)} \cdot {P_{(a_1..a_n)}}^T)_{n,m} = {I_n \cdot (I_m)^T} = \sum_{i=1}^{m}I_{n,i}\cdot ((I_m)^T)_i$

and we see that this is equal to 1 only if $n = m$  which give us I matrix

I want to ask if this is a valid proof that $P * P^T = I$ ??

Comment: I don't understand the notation $P_{(a_1..a_n)} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
I_{a_1,*} \\
\vdots \\
I_{a_n,*} 
\end{pmatrix}$. Can you explain?

Comment: $P_{(a_1..a_n)}$ is any permutation matrix with permutation given as it's 'argument' And $I_{x, *}$ is a row number $x$ of identity matrix

Comment: Also the title is not coherent with the question. In the title you speak of the inverse and you use the transpose in the question. By the way this may be the same in your case and using it maybe interesting!

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Sorry, my bad

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net . Yeah exacpty. I wanted to proof that the Transposed Matrix of Permutation Matrix is it's own inverse so , I did a little mistake

Comment: Actually, you can consider the 3 elementary permutation matrix in 2-dim or 3-dim space. It's easy to check this claim in low-dimensional space, and then in a similar manner, prove it in high dimensional space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Some answers...**

*Using coordinates*. This is what you did which looks correct.

*Using [orthogonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix)*. A permutation matrix... permutes the elements of an orthonormal basis. Therefore it is an orthogonal matrix. Therefore its transpose is equal to its inverse.